# XML value testing with Array

Tags: c#, .net, xml, arrays

In a C# program I'm receiving a value from the XML, then I need to test this against an array. If the value is found in the array return true else return false. Here is the code:

```
 private static bool check(string filename)
 {
 string[] arr = new string[7] {"123", "456", "789", "1012", "1314", "1516", "1781"};

   XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
   xml.Load(filename);


   XmlNode x = xml.SelectSingleNode(@"/abc/def/efg/s");   
    string result = x.InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    for (int i=0; i<arr[i].Length ;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arr[i] + " " + i);
        if (arr[i] == result)
        { return true; }

     }

    return false; 
    }
```

I'm getting an exception:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the boundary of the
>   array.

Now this exception comes up if the match was not found. If the match is found it successfully returns true. Why is it giving an exception on returning false: Here is how I'm calling the method from another method:

```
 if (check(FileName))
 {
  // do something
  }
```

Please advise whats wrong with the code if the match is not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop condition is wrong, you need to test`i` against the length of the array:

```
i < arr.Length
```

Comment: Although based on the data `arr[i].Length` is never greater than 4.  Maybe that was a typo?

Comment: Yes works, I was an idiot to have not seen that. You've bullet eyes, thanks buddy